# Firebase com Javascript - Obter o título da child da database

Tags: javascript, jquery, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, firebase

Bom pessoal, necessito capturar com javascript o nome das childs **10de2017** e **11de2017** da database da imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inicialmente tentei da seguinte forma:

```
var datasWO = firebase.database().ref().child("WO"); //acesso o primeiro child depois do ref.
    datasWO.on("child_added", function (snap2){
        snap2.forEach(function(childSnap){
            console.log(childSnap.key); //e então mostro o nome deles
        });

})
```

Nesse caso ele me retorna os nomes das `childs` que estão dentro de `10de2017` e `11de2017`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei utilizar o `child.parent.key` (Que logicamente iria me retornar 10de2017 e 11de2017) porém recebo no console uma mensagem de erro: `Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`. Preciso listar esses nodes para adicioná-los automaticamente em um select html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, o problema estava no `Child_added`. Usando o `Value` eu consigo obter a key do primeiro child depois do WO.

```
var datasWO = firebase.database().ref("WO");


datasWO.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
        console.log(child.key);
    });
});
```